# php echo output ghost char in arduino client

Tags: php, c, arduino

I try to get a timeStamp from php page (http://www.honeyshare.cn/time.php) and use LinkIt ONE board which is Compatible with arduino as client.There is only one line code "echo time();" on php page.Then I get serial output like this

```
Connecting to AP
Connecting to WebSite
waiting HTTP response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 09:17:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html

7
1450605837
0

disconnected by server
```

1450605837 is what I want.7 above this line and 0 below this line is ghost char.If I would not use echo and only write 1450605837 in php file as string, 7 or 0 will not show in the serial output.

Here is LinkIt ONE board code

```
#include <LTask.h>
#include <LWiFi.h>
#include <LWiFiClient.h>
#define WIFI_AP "XXXX"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "XXXXX"
#define WIFI_AUTH LWIFI_WPA  // choose from LWIFI_OPEN, LWIFI_WPA, or LWIFI_WEP.
#define SITE_URL "www.honeyshare.cn"

LWiFiClient c;

void setup()
{
  LWiFi.begin();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // keep retrying until connected to AP
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP");
  while (0 == LWiFi.connect(WIFI_AP, LWiFiLoginInfo(WIFI_AUTH, WIFI_PASSWORD)))
  {
    delay(1000);
  }

  // keep retrying until connected to website
  Serial.println("Connecting to WebSite");
  while (0 == c.connect(SITE_URL, 80))
  {
    Serial.println("Re-Connecting to WebSite");
    delay(1000);
  }

  // send HTTP request, ends with 2 CR/LF
//  Serial.println("send HTTP GET request");
  c.println("GET /time.php HTTP/1.1");
  c.println("Host: " SITE_URL);
  c.println("Connection: close");
  c.println();

  // waiting for server response
  Serial.println("waiting HTTP response:");
  while (!c.available())
  {
    delay(100);
  }
}

boolean disconnectedMsg = false;

void loop()
{
  // Make sure we are connected, and dump the response content to Serial
  while (c)
  {
    int v = c.read();
    if (v != -1)
    {
      Serial.print((char)v);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("no more content, disconnect");
      c.stop();
      while (1)
      {
        delay(1);
      }
    }
  }

  if (!disconnectedMsg)
  {
    Serial.println("disconnected by server");
    disconnectedMsg = true;
  }
 delay(500);
}
```

Is there any idea about this problem? thx

Comment: I thought they are length used in the "chunked" encoding, but it is weird that the length is `7` instead `a` because they are 10 characters in `1450605837`.

Comment: I can't see what difference it would make, since I'd expect it to prevent compilation. However, `c.println("Host: " SITE_URL);` seems suspect to me, perhaps there's a comma missing immediately before `SITE_URL`? Using both the dev-tools in Chrome and a small utility I wrote, I'm not seeing either the 7 or the 0 in the output I'm receiving.

Comment: the numbers are coming from this line: `Serial.print((char)v);`

Comment: @enhzflep `c.println("Host: " SITE_URL);` is valid. Consecuetive string literals are compiled as if they were one string literal whose cintents are what their contents concatenated.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks so much.I believe the "chunked" encoding make the extra number. May be echo time(); output the numeric types make length is 7?And has any idea to Separate the ‘1450605837’ from all the text?

Comment: @enhzflep thx,I thought the Chrome or a small utility you wrote has parsing HTTP1.1 encoding automatic.

Comment: How about just not allowing the server to use chunked encoding by using HTTP 1.0 by the client if you don't want to parse them?

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you so much.